# Django how to send variable to ajax call and update javascript value

Tags: ajax, django

I have a script on my page that takes a variable, but this variable is first created after a form is submitted. How can I create an AJAX call to my views after a user hits the submit button and then request the variable `myID` and then update my javascript on the html page with the value that it received?

The javascript that needs to be updated:

```
<script>
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId: "{{myID}}",
    }).then(function (result) {
      // Diplay result.error.message to your customer
    });
    </script>
  <script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a view that returns JSON with the myID field and you are using ajax. You can make a post request and use the response to get the myID value.

```
$.post("{% url 'view-url-name' %}, form_data, function(data, status){
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId: data.myID,
}).then(function (result) {
  // Diplay result.error.message to your customer
});
  });
```